# React Native Android gradle multiDexKeepFile and multiDexKeepProguard properties - how to include classes from third-party libraries?

Tags: android, android-multidex

After a recent Android app update, it crashes after being opened for the first time. This is due to a `multiDex` issue according to log file outputs. In the Play developer console I'm getting 
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` errors like this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcel.zzxK (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcfv.<init> (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcgk.<init> (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcgk.zzbj (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcgb.onReceive (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver.onReceive (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:2725)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1421)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5417)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I attempted to follow the advice on the [Android developer Multidex page](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html). My `minSdkVersion` is 16 so I included both the `multiDexEnabled true` configuration and `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` dependency. My Application class extends `MultiDexApplication`.

In the app-level `build.gradle`, I have both `multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')` and `multiDexKeepProguard 'multidex-config.pro'` within android > buildTypes > release section.

The `multidex-config.pro` file within the same directory as app build.gradle consists of one line:

```
-keep com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver.class
```

And multidex-config.txt in that directory has:

```
com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver.class
```

However, when I try to create a release build apk by running `npm run build-android-prod` (my npm script for that is `export ENVFILE=.env.prod && cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease && cd ..`), it ends up failing with the last few lines being:

```
  Copying resources from program directory [/Users/patneedham/Desktop/dev/react-native/MyApp/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJavaRes/release/folders/2/1f/main] (filtered)
  Copying resources from program directory [/Users/patneedham/Desktop/dev/react-native/MyApp/android/app/build/intermediates/classes/release] (filtered)
Printing classes to [/Users/patneedham/Desktop/dev/react-native/MyApp/android/app/build/outputs/mapping/release/dump.txt]...
:app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: proguard.ParseException: Unexpected keyword 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver.class' in line 1 of file '/Users/patneedham/Desktop/dev/react-native/MyApp/android/app/multidex-config.pro'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 29.609 secs

npm ERR! Darwin 16.7.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.8.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build-android-prod" "--stacktrace" "--debug"
npm ERR! node v7.8.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! MyApp@0.0.1 build-android-prod: `export ENVFILE=.env.prod && cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease && cd ..`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
...
```

The line that bugs me is: `com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: proguard.ParseException: Unexpected keyword 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver.class' in line 1 of file '/Users/patneedham/Desktop/dev/react-native/MyApp/android/app/multidex-config.pro'`

Okay I realized I forgot the `class` keyword, so I added that in between `-keep` and `com.google...`, build was successful, and uploaded to Google Play alpha channel yet the same first-open app crash occurs. To be more clear about this, when I click the "Open" button from the Google play store screen, after a second or two I see a white screen for another second, then it closes with the default app crash alert saying 'Unfortunately, MyApp has stopped.'

How can I prevent this `NoClassDefFoundError` when the app first opens?

Comment: First of all, let's verify that the problematic class is indeed absent. You can use Android Studio's `Apk Analyzer` for that. Additionally, Android Studio 3.0 (currently in Beta) makes it easier to trace and fix Proguard issues - make sure to watch the [relevant video from io17](https://youtu.be/AdfKNgyT438?t=26m41s).